# Example of two function $f,g$ so that the convolution is not in $C_0$

Tags: real-analysis

I have the function $f \in L^1$ and $g \in L^\infty$.

If $f \star g\notin C_0$ then $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow+\infty} (f \star g)(x) \ne 0$.

My ideas is to take $g=1$ but for the function $f$?

Comment: If $g=1$, what is $f\star g$?

Comment: $\int f(x-y) dy$

Comment: Take $f$ to be the indicator function of $[0,1]$ then $f *g = 1$.

Comment: Take any $f$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R} f \ne 0.$

Comment: And does $\int f(x-y)dy$ actually depend on $x$?

Answer (score 0):

$(f \star g)(x)=(g \star f)(x)=\int_R g(x-y)f(y)dy=\int_R \chi_{[0,1]}(y) dy=1$

It's right?